# "Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon" after uninstalling LightDM

Tags: server, lightdm

I'm a rather new Linux user and tried making my *virtual* server login automatic and while doing so I installed lightdm.

I noticed that I got the graphical UI on boot but couldn't log in, so I deleted it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

and now I get:

> Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon

on startup. I can ssh onto the server and everything seems to be working except the "main server window".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed. I had to revert it to one of the back-ups.
I would still be interested in a way to properly fix it if anyone cares to write it.